# How To Load Text File Items To ListView VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have created ListView1 with 5 columns.
Each column has different name and I need to 'load' from my PC by open dialog function and add text file in ListView1.
The problem is that once I proceed and load txt file in ListView1, it doesnt reconize specific 'values' like "proxy" --> to 'Proxy column' "IP" --> to 'IP' column etc....
I am adding formate from text file like this: 192.169.0.1:8080 and thats all I need to add only this 2 values in colmuns by tag name. The other column names are there because when I will check the proxies, It will display (speed, protocol and type)
So here ismy code already:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.GridLines = True
    ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
    ListView1.HideSelection = False
    ListView1.MultiSelect = False
    ListView1.Columns.Add("IP", 90, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Port", 40, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Protocol", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Type", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Speed", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim filepath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim inputstream As New IO.StreamReader(filepath)
    Dim newstr(2) As String
    Dim IP As String
    Dim Port As String
    Dim Protocol As String
    Dim Type As String
    Dim Speed As String

    'Read while there is mor characters to read
    Do While inputstream.Peek <> -1
        'Split each line containing Account|Password into the array
        newstr = inputstream.ReadLine().Split("|")
        'Assigm the values to the variables
        IP = newstr(0)
        Port = newstr(1)
        Protocol = newstr(2)
        Type = newstr(3)
        Speed = newstr(4)

        'Add them to the list
        Me.ListView1.Items.Add(IP)
        Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Port)
        Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Protocol)
        Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Type)
        Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Speed)
    Loop

    inputstream.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        ListView1.Items.Remove(Item)
    Next
End Sub
```

SO Could you someone tell me HOW TO ADD CODE to open dialog recognize my first 2 attributes values and add them to columns correctly? thx

Comment: you are just adding the Port value over and over: `SubItems.Add(Port)`; dont you want them to be the other values you split?

Comment: Sorry I forgot this will nto be an issue only before that show me this error:[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/qq20ck.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: That particular error is telling that your `newstr` array doesn't have more than 1 item in it.  You should probably check for blank lines or lines with no `|` in them before you perform the split.

Comment: that error has nothing to do with the ListView - there is a problem with the data, format or expected contents.  Use the debugger to examine `newstr` when it happens

Comment: You've limited newstr to 2 items. Change it to Dim newstr() As String

Comment: Vincent = Yes you right thx  changed to () and also tried (5) but not working. Grim = i dont much undertood you said, newstr = what that means pls? im newbie to this,thx guys

Comment: You should declare `newstr` as `Dim newstr() As String` i.e. as a dynamic array instead of fixed size array.

Comment: Plutonix = the debuger says same as on image, really have no idea :/

Comment: Pradeep= when i changed and declare that; i get more errors like i had :(

Answer (score 0):

/) well I deleted from code this:

```
        Protocol = newstr(2)
        Type = newstr(3)
        Speed = newstr(4)
```

and also after under that this:

```
            Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Protocol)
            Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Type)
            Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Speed)
```

AND IT WORKS!!!!
as I needed to insert only IP:PORT format and other info not needed, as it will eb only when validating or scraping in listview1 and not by uploading from PC :D
PS: By the way thx GRIM as he helped me and I changed "|" this to ":" as my proxies are semi-colomn separated, and thx VINCENT as he helped me and I changed " Dim newstr() As String" SO NOW ALL IS OK :-) youpeee :p
..Also sorry I dont saw any option how could i mark this answered by those 2 members, so i answered by myself and I mentioned you there, THANKS!

Comment: yeah and aslo I deleted unused codes:                               Dim Protocol As String
        Dim Type As String
        Dim Speed As String